# VS Code creates empty launch.json instead of detecting debug configurations

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging

I'm just about to set up VSCode on Ubuntu and I tried to debug a C++ file. However, when I try to use Run>Add Configuration it just directly opens `launch.json` without asking me about an installed debug configuration. The automatically created `launch.json` looks like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": []
}
```

I have g++ installed, running `g++ --version` gives me:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I would have figured VSCode detects the installed g++ kit and suggests it to me. Yet this didn't happen. How can I get the debug kit suggestion box back?

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

Check for Installed Extensions:

Make sure you have the necessary extensions installed for C++ development in VSCode. You should have at least the "C/C++" extension by Microsoft installed. You can check and install extensions by going to the Extensions view (Ctrl+Shift+X).

Configure Tasks:

Before you can create a launch configuration, you need to have a task configuration set up. To do this, you'll need to create a tasks.json file. You can do this by clicking on the "Terminal" menu and selecting "Configure Tasks". Choose "Create tasks.json file from template" and select "Others".

If you've already done this and it's still not working, double-check that the tasks.json file is correctly set up.

Manually Add Configuration:

If the automatic configuration is not working, you can manually add a configuration to the launch.json file.
example configuration for a C++ program:
`{ "version": "0.2.0", "configurations": [ { "name": "C++ Debug", "type": "cppdbg", "request": "launch", "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out", "args": [], "stopAtEntry": false, "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}", "environment": [], "externalConsole": false, "MIMode": "gdb", "setupCommands": [ { "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb", "text": "-enable-pretty-printing", "ignoreFailures": true } ], "preLaunchTask": "build", "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb" } ] }` 
Adjust the "program" field to point to the correct location of your compiled C++ executable.

Restart VSCode:

After making any changes to the configuration files, it's a good idea to restart VSCode to ensure the changes take effect.

Check Compiler Path:

In some cases, VSCode might not be able to automatically detect the compiler path. You can specify it manually by adding a "compilerPath" field to your c_cpp_properties.json file:
`{ "configurations": [ { "name": "Linux", "includePath": [ "${workspaceFolder}/**" ], "defines": [], "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++", "cStandard": "c11", "cppStandard": "c++17", "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64" } ], "version": 4 }` 
Verify Workspace Folder:

Ensure that you have opened the correct workspace folder in VSCode where your C++ file is located.

Check for Updates:

Ensure both VSCode and the extensions are up to date.